# What is my folder path in Netlify CMS using Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, netlify, netlify-cms

In the Jekyll config, source is set to `source: ./jekyll`
A collection that lives in that source `./jekyll/_work`
Netlify CMS Config inside admin folder `./jekyll/admin/config.yml`

## The path to the folder where the documents are stored

Collection path references from the admin config `folder: "_work"`

The admin CMS actually creates this folder in the root of the repo with the html file inside of it

### [Question] The path to the folder where the documents are stored

Does the admin config path have to include the Jekyll source again e.g. folder: "../jekyll/_work"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder paths in the Netlify CMS `config.yml` are relative to the root of your repository.

### In this case:

folder: "jekyll/_work"

#### ***Notes:***

- `media_folder` is also relative to the root of the repository
- Do NOT prefix your paths with location starts (ie "./" or "/")